# I want to save captured image in an Object (Windows Phone App)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i am working in windows Phone 7 Application. using this code i captured the image and saved into Media Library

```
myCamera.Show();
```

and this is for Saving to media Library

```
mediaLibrary.SavePicture("TestPhoto", imageBits);
```

My Question is > I want to save my captured image into an Object Where i can directly send to server

Comment: As far as I can see, you could just send imageBits, couldn't you?

Comment: @Robert How can i save this image bits into an Object???

Comment: WHat do you mean by "object"? It IS (most probably) a byte array. You would only have to make sure that the server expects a byte array, then you can save it to file or to a DB as a BLOB or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imageBits` is already an object (of type `Stream`) so what you're asking for doesn't really make sense. Presumably you're trying to convert it to a byte array in order to send it to the server.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
//if you've manipulated stream before this call, reset position
e.ChosenPhoto.Position = 0;
e.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(ms);
byte[] imageByteArray = ms.ToArray();
ms.Dispose();
```

`imageByteArray` then contains your image as a byte array. Alternatively, you could convert the image into a `Base64` encoded string and send that, but that depends if your server can decode it.

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageByteArray);
```

Comment: can you tell one thing, what is Dispose() stand for...?

Comment: If the class implements the `IDisposable` interface, it's usually a good idea to call it to remove any unmanaged resources (which helps avoid memory leaks). Calling `Dipose` closes the stream, since we no longer need it, and essentially cleans up after the oject and marks it ready for removal by the garbage collector. You can do the same thing with a `using` block [as shown here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using).